# Linked list for text editor in c++

Tags: c++, list, text, linked-list, editor

Im trying to write a text editor in c++. And each line of text has to go into a node of a linked list. Ive got must of the linked list finished, all I need now is how to put each line of text into each node. Thats my question, how to put each line of text into each node.

Here's my code:

```
typedef int ListItemType;

typedef Strac Node* NodePtr;

Struc Node
{
    ListItemType data;
    NodePtr next;
};

int main()
{
    //Create empty list
    NodePtr head = NULL;

    //1st node
    head = new Node;

    //Initialize the field
    head -> data = ?;

    head -> next = NULL;

    //2nd node
    head -> next = new Node;

    //Initialize the field
    head -> next -> data = ?;

    head -> next -> next = NULL;


}
```

Im guessing that each line of text goes where the question marks are at?

Thanks

Comment: You do _know_ that C++ comes with a list type, yes? Is there some reason why you're implementing your own?

Comment: `Strac` and `Struc`? When you post code, please make sure that as much as possible actually compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Text Editors generally back their editing buffer with a [Rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(computer_science))

Furthermore, there is a standard doubly linked list data structure in C++ called std::list.

If you want to represent a single line of text perhaps you should use a std::string:

```
typedef std::string ListItemType;
```